# lapply with gregexpr and character vector

Tags: r, regex, vector, character, lapply

I'm new to using lapply, etc. My code and data follow...

```
b  = c( "ZFW", "ZTL" )
```

I have a larger character vector, dfNames (length = 147), which contains instances like...

```
dfNames[ 113 ] "arr_to_KEWR_in_ZFW"
dfNames[ 147 ] "arr_to_KEWR_in_ZTL"
```

When I apply this code...

```
indx = which( unlist( lapply( paste( '_in_', b, sep = '' ), function(v){gregexpr( v, dfNames )} ) ) != -1 )
```

I receive a list of integers in indx which is of length at least 294...

```
6  41  58  75 101 118 135 165 200 217 234 260 277 294
```

which produces on dfNames[ indx ]...

```
"all_in_ZFW" "dep_from_KCLT_in_ZFW" "dep_from_KDFW_in_ZFW" "dep_from_KEWR_in_ZFW"
"arr_to_KCLT_in_ZFW"   "arr_to_KDFW_in_ZFW"   "arr_to_KEWR_in_ZFW"   NA                    
NA                     NA                     NA                     NA                    
NA                     NA
```

So, clearly my use of lapply has caused R to wrap around and I'm not returning the indices from dfNames that contain the pattern = 'ZTL'.

Sorry for a dumb question.

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example. Also have a look at `grepl` like `grepl("_ZFW_", list)`.

Comment: Can close.  Using grepl will be fine.  Tx.

Comment: Actually, using grepl on b = c("ZFW", "ZTL" ) creates message that pattern has length > 1, which is why I sought help on using lapply.

Answer (score 0):

What I understand, you are looking then for

```
b = c("ZFW", "ZTL" )
lapply(b, function(x) grepl(x, list))
```

Comment: So then I have a list (2 x 147) of Boolean values; what would be the most efficient manner of returning the composite set of indices == TRUE for both list entries?  E.g., c = lapply( b, function( x) grepl( x, dfNames ) )...c[[1]] = FALSE TRUE FALSE, etc. and c[[2]] = FALSE TRUE TRUE FALSE, etc.

Comment: Please specify a reproducible example including input (sample) and what you expect for the output. Then I can have a look at it again tomorrow.

Comment: Can set data by email if you wish.

Comment: Using `dput` everybody has the information. To me it is still unclear what you expect as output.

Comment: That is how ignorant I am - I've never used dput before.